# How do I aggregate an pre-loaded data set with a user-chosen factor variable?

Tags: r, shiny

**My question:**

I aggregate a user-chosen continuous variable in my pre-loaded data set by a factor variable chosen by the user in the serve function.

I get the following error. It seems that my input variables aren't recognized as column names in the aggregate function.

```
Warning in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How do I aggregate a dataset using reactive inputs?

**Background :**

I'm working on a Shiny app.

One of the things I want it to do is to present a data table of the means of a user-chosen continuous variable by a factor variable which is also chosen by the user.

I'm trying to achieve this by 1) letting the user choose those variable first, and then 2) 'collapse' the data set by the factor variable with the aggregate function.

**My code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Load necessary data ----------------------
data(CO2)

# User interface -----------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

        titlePanel("Calculate Your Own Mean."),


        sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(inputId = "indicator", label = "Indicators:", 
                            choices = names(CO2)[4:length(names(CO2))], 
                            selected = "conc"),
                selectInput(inputId = "group", label = "Disaggregate by:",
                            choices = names(CO2)[1:3], 
                            selected = "Plant"),
                width = 2),

        mainPanel(
                DT::dataTableOutput("table")
        )

)

# Server -----------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

        meanData <-reactive({

                aggregate(input$indicator ~ input$group,
                          data = CO2,
                          FUN = mean)
        })

        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                data <- meanData()
                data
        })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The expected result should show a table with the means of the user chosen variable by the user chosen group variable.

Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values coming from 'input' is character.   So, it needs to be converted to a formula with `paste`

```
aggregate(as.formula(paste0(input$indicator,  " ~ ", input$group)),
                      data = CO2,
                      FUN = mean)
```

a reproducible example wth `CO2`

```
aggregate(as.formula(paste("uptake", "~", "Plant")), 
              data = CO2, FUN = mean)
#   Plant   uptake
#1    Qn1 33.22857
#2    Qn2 35.15714
#3    Qn3 37.61429
#4    Qc1 29.97143
#5    Qc3 32.58571
#6    Qc2 32.70000
#7    Mn3 24.11429
#8    Mn2 27.34286
#9    Mn1 26.40000
#10   Mc2 12.14286
#11   Mc3 17.30000
#12   Mc1 18.00000
```

-fullcode

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Load necessary data ----------------------
data(CO2)

# User interface -----------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Calculate Your Own Mean."),


  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "indicator", label = "Indicators:", 
                choices = names(CO2)[4:length(names(CO2))], 
                selected = "conc"),
    selectInput(inputId = "group", label = "Disaggregate by:",
                choices = names(CO2)[1:3], 
                selected = "Plant"),
    width = 2),

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )

)

# Server -----------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

  meanData <-reactive({

    aggregate(as.formula(paste0(input$indicator,  " ~ ", input$group)),
              data = CO2,
              FUN = mean)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data <- meanData()
    data
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I see it now. I'm still learning R in general as well, and have never really encountered the as.formula function. This gets the exactly the result I wanted. Thank you so much, akrun!